# Mapping complex analysis help?

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the function $w= (-1+ i)z - 2 +3i$  find where $\Re(z)\ge 1$ is mapped...
So $\Re(z)\ge 1$ means $x\ge 1$ ...

How do I relate this to the function so I can do the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $z = x+ i y$, as you have already implicitly done, and also $w = u + i v$.  Now equate the real and imaginary parts of your equation relating $w$ to $z$, and impose $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Oh Jonathan Rhys Meyers,my light at the end of the tunnel.Thank you.

Comment: @Mathfreak: You're welcome.  Feel free to vote up and/or accept my answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Comment: I need to know smth else,what do you mean by impose?

Comment: @Mathfreak: You want to find the image of $x\geq 1$, so once you have an expression for $x$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, setting that expression to be $\geq 1$ gives your solution.  That's all I meant by 'imposing' the condition $x\geq 1$.